# Does the SoftLayer API return the ACTIVE or INACTIVE status of an image?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to get a list of images that are inactive.  Does the SoftLayer API return the ACTIVE or INACTIVE status of an image?  Thanks!

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language the question was written in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoftLayer API returns both images, active and inactive, you can retrieve only inactive images with the following rest call:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectFilter={"blockDeviceTemplateGroups":{"statusId":{"operation":"2"}}}

Method: Get
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Account::getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account)
- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)